# C++/Linux How can I get read permission stat for other users?

Tags: c++, linux, permissions

I'm writing a simple C++ webserver assignment and I want to check if the file is readable by other users. If not, the server will send back 403 Forbidden.

I already have a `statbuf.st_mode` using `stat(FILE,&statbuf)` but I don't know how to retrieve the read permission for other users. I know there is "S_IROTH" but I don't how to use it. I tried to print it to terminal using `cout<<S_IROTH<<endl;` and it was 4 but "FILE" has a permission of 0440 so I guess I was not printing the S_IROTH of "FILE".

So my question is: How to get read permission stat for other users?
Or am I making any mistake in concept here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mask the mode of the file against `S_IROTH`. Also, you're passing `statbuf` incorrectly (and you should be getting a warning for it). The correct code should look like:

```
int result = stat(path, &statbuf);
if (result != 0) {
    return NOT_FOUND;
}
if (!(statbuf.st_mode & S_IROTH)) {
    return FORBIDDEN;
}
... success, continue ...
```

Comment: It was a typo cause I didn't copy paste my code...I've corrected it. And your code is working, thanks a lot!